# Is there a way to express $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\,\,B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: summation, beta-function

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758769/any-other-methods-for-evaluating-int-0-frac-pi4-frac-arctan-cosx/4758851#4758851), I face the problem of making explicit (even in terms of special functions)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\,\,B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ which is
$$1.4898960823080587137464656088853266206604466782309\cdots$$

The summation converges very fast

- It is alternating
- The first term is already $1.57080$
- The ratio of two consecutive summands is asymptotic to $\frac 12$

`Any idea ?`

Comment: Your series is: $$2 C-\frac{1}{3} \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{9}\right)$$ using Mathematica packages in here: https://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html

Comment: Where `C` is  Catalan constant.

Comment: Simplifying with Wolfram cloud gives $2C-\frac{i\pi^2}4+\frac12\ln(-17-12\sqrt 2) \csc^{-1}(3)-i\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{-2\sqrt 2-i}3\right)+i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2\sqrt2+i}3\right)$. The dilogarithms are an [inverse tangent integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Thank you very much !